Match Matplotlib Fonts to Overleaf Document Fonts
I’m writing a report in Overleaf, and I want the fonts in my Matplotlib plots (legends, axis labels, and tick labels) to match the font used in my Overleaf document. So I won’t have to squint to see the captions.
Here are the Overleaf document details:
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.75em}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

I’m using Jupyter Notebook to generate plots. Before plotting, I’ve tried the following to set the font:
mpl.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
mpl.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Arial'

My plots are simple scatter plots or figures with two subplots. However, I’m struggling to ensure that the font in the figures matches the Overleaf document font (e.g., Times New Roman or Computer Modern). How can I ensure consistency for all the different plots?

Matplotlib can export to pgfplots, i.e., the graph itself is rendered by Matplotlib but all text elements are rendered by LaTeX, with the font settings of the document. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/pgf.html.
